# How i receive curl post data in php

Tags: php, curl

When i close the curl then it will give me warning and how i will receive data which i send using curl.here is my code.variable $data contain my URL where i want to send my data.any one can help me?

```
<?php
$ch=curl_init($data);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "url=http://mydomain.com/newc/index.php");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$returndata=curl_exec($ch);
echo $returndata;
curl_close($returndata);
?>
```

Comment: Do you want to know how to get the posted data at http://mydomain.com/newc/index.php, or do you want to know how to get the answer from that url in the script you posted?

Comment: You have to close the cURL connection not your data string ;-). `curl_close($returndata);` should be `curl_close($ch);` in your case.

Comment: i don't know how to get data from cURL posted data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This:**

```
$datatopost = array("url" => "http://mydomain.com/newc/index.php" );
$ch= curl_init($data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datatopost);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$returndata = curl_exec($ch);
echo $returndata;
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Thanks.just missed it.